# Localization menu with reading from xml-files

Tags: java, xml, xslt, localization, menu

I have next problem. For my web-application on java I use 2 variant of menu for Tutor and Student. After that, depending on the role of the logged-on user, I transform the xml file in html and is included in the page. It means that I should use 4 xml file and 4 html file ( in case if I want to use localization 2 locales and multithread-app), get current locale and choose file source and result for transformation or exists other way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have 2 different kinds of views, each in 2 possible languages:

- View (page) for tutors

  - In English
  - In second language
- View for students

  - In English
  - In second language

As far as I know, there is no standard utility to define different views for the same page (for tutors and for students in your case), because it will greatly depend on the application. So you can use any approach. Your approach with different XML sources sounds just fine.

As for the locale, the standard approach is to use [Java Resource Bundles](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/). There are also other utilities for internationalisation, such as [cosmopolitan](https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n/wiki/Overview), etc. Using this will give you the advantage of separation of XML files from language translations, so you will only need to have 2 XML files. This also means that if you change your XML file for English, you will not need to make the same change in XML file to the second language.

However, you will need to avoid storing localisable text in the XML files, and instead store special *keys* that will be used to get the correct text for the current locale.

For example:

```
<page>
  <title>${title}</title>
  <body>
    <heading>${heading}</heading>

    ${introduction}

    Copyright (c) 2012
  </body>
</page>
```

Then you can define the translations for the localisable parts (such as `${title}`, `${heading}`) in, for example, a properties file:

```
#In Translations_en.properties file
title=Page for tutors
heading=Introduction
introduction=Welcome to the tutors page!

#In Translations_<yourlanguage>.properties file
title=...
heading=...
introduction=...
```

Then modify your XML -> HTML conversion process to extract keys in for `${key}` and replace them with the value for one of *.properties* files based on the current locale.

**Edit:**

You can try this:

1) Start off with your XML template (let's simplify it a bit):

```
<!-- tutor.xml -->
<page>
  <title>${title}</title>
</page>
```

2) Create and apply a pre-processor to convert your template into localised templates, for each language. The output should look like:

```
<!-- tutor_en.xml -->
<page>
  <title>Title</title>
</page>

<!-- tutor_ru.xml -->
<page>
  <title>Название</title>
</page>
```

3) Transform and load the appropriate template at runtime. Roughly, your code will look like:

```
// Get xml template name based on current locale
String getLocalisedTemplate(String baseName){
  return baseName + "_" + Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() + ".xml";
}

public String renderPage(){
  if(currentUser.isTutor()){
    //This will be tutor_en.xml or tutor_ru.xml
    String templateFile = getLocalisedTemplate("tutor");

    //Return localised and transformed HTML
    return applyXslt("tutor.xslt", templateFile);
  } else if (currentUser.isStudent()){
    // same as above replacing tutor with student
  }
}
```

I used `Locale.getDefault()` for illustration purposes, in your application you would probably have a different way of determining the current user locale (maybe from user settings).

In essence, the above approach is very similar to your original proposal. The only difference, is that localised XML files are generated automatically in step 2 from an XML template, so you don't have to manage them by hand.

Regarding the simultaneous use by users, there should be no clashing between users' views. This will depend on how you are deploying your interface: a desktop Java app, an applet, a web-based app, etc. Which ever approach you are taking, each user should be having his/her own JVM instance or own session, decoupled from other users.

Comment: It's a good advice for xml-files, but for html .. not. Because in case if tutors or students will use this app in the same time with different locales file menu for tutor will be overwrite on new locale. As I understand I should use 2 xml-file, 2 property-file and 4 html-file, shouldn't it?

Comment: I've realised that you are using XLST to convert XML to HTML, right? It might be tricky to convert `${variable}` parts with XSLT, so it might be better to instead convert each XML file (say, `input.xml`) into 2 XML files for each language (e.g. `input_en.xml` and `input_yourlang.xml`), using a simple Java program. Then you can just apply XSLT transformation on the required xml file at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing XSLT transformation. But if I use EL-expression in xml and after that I get html file and fmt not suitable tag for html... I can't understand your idea